# Angular multiple ng Class

Tags: css, angular

I have 2 class which are , I only want to enable or use the 2 class if it met the condition which is dealDispositionFormFields.isSubtenantTakingFullSpace === 'No'

How do we create the syntax for that using ngClass ? Thanks.

1. use deal-form-date-picker
2. enabled-input

How do we implement multiple class using ng class in angular ?  . for example I want to use deal-form-date-picker  class and enabled-input class if dealDispositionFormFields.isSubtenantTakingFullSpace === 'No'

#code

```
class="opacity87" [ngClass]="{'enabled-input':dealDispositionFormFields.isSubtenantTakingFullSpace === 'No'}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add multiple classes and use your condition, ie.

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

see [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)